# Why the position of ORDER BY clause is different between PERCENT_RANK and PERCENTILE_CONT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I noticed in all SQL-family languages (T-SQL, U-SQL, etc.), the ORDER_BY clause is required to be put inside the OVER clause for [PERCENT_RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percent-rank-transact-sql), like:

```
PERCENT_RANK( )  
    OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )
```

But for [PERCENTILE_CONT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql) and [PERCENTILE_DISC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-disc-transact-sql), ORDER_BY clause needs to be put outside the OVER like:

```
PERCENTILE_CONT ( numeric_literal )   
    WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY order_by_expression [ ASC | DESC ] )  
    OVER ( [ <partition_by_clause> ] )
```

I am curious what are the design considerations behind this difference?